# Rational canonical form of $\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 12 & 4 \\ -8 & -16 & -4 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> What is the rational canonical form of
>   $$ \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 12 & 4 \\ -8 & -16 & -4 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Its characteristic polynomial is $(x-4)^3$ and its minimal poly is $(x-4)^2$.

Does this mean its rational canonical form is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -16 \\ 0 & 1 & 8 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$?

Comment: That is the correct rcf.  Are you just looking for this confirmation?

Comment: Thnk you. Yes i am.